# Linux Kernel Mapping Physical Memory for DMA

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I'm developing on an embedded system that has a DSP and a CPU. There is a shared memory region between the DSP and CPU. The DSP processes data and signals to the CPU when data is ready. I'm running Linux on the CPU and have excluded the shared memory region from the kernel mapping.

I have Linux kernel driver code that can ioremap the physical address sent by the DSP. Using the returned virtual address, I can inspect the data and see that the data looks valid. I'm now having trouble trying to map the data so I can DMA it out of the CPU to a peripheral device. I want to avoid copying the data to a dma_alloc_coherent region to minimize latency.

I believe this is because there is an IOMMU between the memory and the device doing the DMA. What do I need to do in order to generate the dma address to physical address mapping?

Comment: Here is some general info, it may help as a starting point: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37525651/linux-iommu-page-tables